# Catch dynamically pass arguments to test cases

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project which is being tested using [Catch.cpp](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch):

I compile and run the following file to run my tests:

```
 #define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
 #include "catch.hpp"
 #include "test1.h"
 #include "test2.h"
```

In the near future I'll want to run more complex tests, that require command line arguments.

In Other words, I would like to apply some logic to my tests runs, being able to run them from inside loops or conditions and pass variables to them.

I found this page: [Supply your own main](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md).

which seems like a good direction but i could not find a more detailed explanation.

Can this be done by catch? or maybe there is a better way to implement what i described?

Comment: You might be looking for parameterized tests. However, Catch doesn't support them yet, to my knowledge. For unit tests, you wouldn't really want those input values changing from run to run.

Comment: You probably want to use a more advanced testing framework like [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest).

Answer (score 1):

What I managed to do is to write my own `main`, parse the command line and store the needed parameter (in my case an IP) in a global variable. Not the most beautiful code, but does the job:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"

std::string IP;

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    Catch::Session session;

    int returnCode = session.applyCommandLine(argc, argv, Catch::Session::OnUnusedOptions::Ignore);
    if (returnCode != 0)
        return returnCode;

    for (auto token : session.unusedTokens()) {
        printf("Token: %s\n", token.data.c_str());
        IP = token.data;
    }

    return session.run();
}
```

I then run this as `TestRunner.exe [test-case-tag] --MY_IP_HERE`. Note that without the "--" in front of the parameter, they don't appear in the `unusedTokens`.

Comment: This doesn't compile anymore, because ```OnUnusedOptions``` and ```unusedTokens()``` don't exist (anymore).

Comment: What does work, though, is adding your own command line option(s): https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/own-main.md#adding-your-own-command-line-options

Comment: I've applied both strategies (adding a new command line option, and store its value into a global variable). Despite it works, I feel this solution rather counterintuitive (I would expect some other mechanism to inject the command line to specific tests). Is there any other way to inject custom arguments to specific tests?