# How to access custom command line options from within a Catch2 test case?

Tags: c++, command-line, catch2

I added my own command line option using a [custom main file](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/own-main.md#adding-your-own-command-line-options)<sup>†</sup>:

<sup>†</sup>https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/own-main.md#adding-your-own-command-line-options

```
  // ...
  auto cli 
    = session.cli() // Get Catch's composite command line parser
    | Opt( height, "height" ) // bind variable to a new option, with a hint string
        ["-g"]["--height"]    // the option names it will respond to
        ("how high?");        // description string for the help output

  // ...
}
```

Now I want to use the `height` command line option from within a test case. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't find any other way than by adding a global variable, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530546/catch-dynamically-pass-arguments-to-test-cases
I looked through the source code. ```runTests()``` is a non-member function and is called with an argument of type ```Config```, which sounds promising but doesn't appear to expose any access to command line options :/

Comment: When adding your own command line option, the option letters already taken are ```abcdefilorstvwx#```, as you can look up in ```catch::makeCommandLineParser( ConfigData& )```. Empty option names are not allowed, so use one of ```ghjkmnpquyz``` or special characters.